# Clearing all divs by default

Tags: html, css, boilerplate

Is there any reason why divs aren't naturally cleared?

As per the Boilerplate helper classes, adding the `clearfix` class to an element applies the following styles:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

So throughout my HTML, where ever I have floated elements I add `class="clearfix"` to the parent element. Would it not be easier to just apply all the above styles to all divs, like so:

```
div:before,
div:after,
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

div:after,
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

div,
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

I can't seem to identify any scenario in which this would be an issue, at the very least any conflicts would require a simple override.

Comment: show your HTML as well please .

Comment: all divs?  wouldn't that prevent you from actually floating div's next to each other?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with adding superfluous css throughout your document. Just keep in mind that code that assumes floated elements won't contribute to the height of the parent element ( default behavior ) will break.

Comment: @DomDay Naturally. I've been experimenting with the changes I proposed, and I haven't noticed anything broken (yet to check IE :S)

Comment: It should be fine. Your only concern would be plugins and other third party code which create/insert their own html, and expect certain behaviors from their `div`s

Comment: Yeah, so it's horribly broken in Firefox at least. Was just trying to understand the reason not to do it.